# Are there any Code Golf statistics available?

Tags: discussion, statistics, code-golf

I don't know if this is the appropriate place to post this but I was just wondering if there is an app or website that looks at all the code golf q's, their answers and shows which language tends to win on average? Something that parses each answer for char count for different languages and then plots which language on avg answers a code-golf question in how many characters and so on?

It might be interesting to see this ...

Comment: Why would it be interesting?  Many people find code golf to be a useful exercise, but does anyone believe languages which tend to "win" often indicates anything other than which languages tend to "win" code golf often?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write a SEDE query to do it; the main problem is figuring out what language each answer was written in. Many answers use the convention of saying the language at the very beginning, but based on the results from [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/9772/), it looks like a lot don't